# How to read off automatically set color range of Makie heatmap?

Tags: julia

Is there a way to get the current automatically set color range of a Makie heatmap plot?

If I create a heatmap and check the `colorrange` attribute, I get this.

```
julia> _,_,hp = heatmap( randn(16,16) )

julia> hp.colorrange
Observable{Any}(MakieCore.Automatic())
    0 => map((::Makie.var"#79#86")(color, crange) @ Makie ~/.julia/packages/Makie/uAmck/src/colorsampler.jl:233)

julia> hp.colorrange[]
MakieCore.Automatic()
```

Is there a way to retrieve the current color range min and max out of the `MakieCore.Automatic` color range object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that works.  Create the heatmap, add a colorbar, then read the limits out of the colorbar:

```
julia> hf,ha,hp = heatmap( randn(16,16) )

julia> hb = Colorbar( hf[1,2], hp )
Colorbar()
```

[image]

```
julia> hb.limits[]
2-element Vec2{Float64} with indices SOneTo(2):
 -2.3940300941467285
  3.205148220062256
```

A bit roundabout because you have to create an additional object but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The MakieCore.Automatic label is a placeholder to indicate Makie will use its internal defaults, and afaik that label does not refer directly to any color list, so you cannot get the colors from that label directly.

However, the documentation for Makie states that Makie uses color schemes such as those maintained in ColorSchemes.jl. Since :viridis is the default color scheme, you can get the colors with

```
julia> using ColorSchemes

julia> cgrad(:viridis)
PlotUtils.ContinuousColorGradient(ColorScheme{Vector{RGBA{Float64}}, String, String}(RGBA{Float64}[RGBA{Float64}(0.267004,0.004874,0.329415,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.26851,0.009605,0.335427,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.269944,0.014625,0.341379,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.271305,0.019942,0.347269,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.272594,0.025563,0.353093,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.273809,0.031497,0.358853,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.274952,0.037752,0.364543,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.276022,0.044167,0.370164,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.277018,0.050344,0.375715,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.277941,0.056324,0.381191,1.0)  …  RGBA{Float64}(0.906311,0.894855,0.098125,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.916242,0.896091,0.100717,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.926106,0.89733,0.104071,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.935904,0.89857,0.108131,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.945636,0.899815,0.112838,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.9553,0.901065,0.118128,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.964894,0.902323,0.123941,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.974417,0.90359,0.130215,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.983868,0.904867,0.136897,1.0), RGBA{Float64}(0.993248,0.906157,0.143936,1.0)], "", ""), [0.0, 0.00392156862745098, 0.00784313725490196, 0.011764705882352941, 0.01568627450980392, 0.0196078431372549, 0.023529411764705882, 0.027450980392156862, 0.03137254901960784, 0.03529411764705882  …  0.9647058823529412, 0.9686274509803922, 0.9725490196078431, 0.9764705882352941, 0.9803921568627451, 0.984313725490196, 0.9882352941176471, 0.9921568627450981, 0.996078431372549, 1.0])
```

So, the first color is RGBA{Float64}(0.267004,0.004874,0.329415,1.0) and the last RGBA{Float64}(0.993248,0.906157,0.143936,1.0). See also the documentation at https://juliadatascience.io/makie_colors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that isn't what I am asking.  I want the color range limits, not the colors themselves.

Comment: Hmm. What kind of answer format do you seek? Two numbers that are extrema, a vector of numbers, a vector of color values, a vector of your data values, or a 2D or 3D array of values of some kind?

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear.  See my answer.

Comment: You just wanted the extrema of your data. This is only related to color because you are plotting.

Comment: I am aware of this.